# Eclipse: How to jump to last edit location in current editor?

Tags: eclipse

Ctrl+Q may redirect to another editor, but I want to stay with current one but jump to place of last edit, for currently opened editor.

Is it possible? Maybe some plugins could do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uhm, as in, undo and then redo. That is, press `Ctrl + Z`, and then `Ctrl + Y`.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `ALT + LEFT` and `ALT + RIGHT` to jump back and forth, though this also involves editor changes, so might not be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand you correctly, Ctrl-Q is switching to another editor for you (leaving eclipe), rather than going to the last change you made within eclipse. The default key combo for going to the last change you made **IS** Ctrl+Q in eclipse, for most people this is all you need. Sounds like you've got a special situation though. In your case, I would suggest going to Window - Preferences - General - Keys - and then start typing "Last" (or scrolling down) to find Last Edit Location in the list. Then you can set it to whatever you want and use that instead of undoing and redoing changes.

Comment: also Ctrl + alt + <-